# Mathematica is not multiplying through

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Here is an expression to which I’m applying rules:

```
In[141]:= br1noOutQuadOne /. theThetas /. theMC /. theS
Out[141]= {p1 -> 1/2 (-3.7249*10^6 + p2)}
```

I’m mystified why the 1/2 doesn’t multiply through. Here's another way that doesn't work:

```
In[142]:= Simplify[N[br1noOutQuadOne /. theThetas /. theMC /. theS]]
Out[142]= {p1 -> 0.5 (-3.7249*10^6 + p2)}
```

Comment: my guess that `-3..10^6` is actually a string or similar.  Mathematica uses 'x' not '*' in scientific notation for floats.

Comment: Try `FullForm[...your replacement expression...]` to see what MMA might be hiding from you

Comment: Nope, not a string. Yes, `FullForm` was what I ended up using to dig through to the culprit. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version *Mathematica* is doing what it does and not reducing the precision of an exact number, such as `1/2`, without explicit instruction to do so.  Multiplying the term `1/2 * -3.7249*10^6` will lose precision.

In the second version *Mathematica* is showing that it thinks that `0.5 (-3.7249*10^6 + p2)` **is** simpler than `-1.86245*10^6 + 0.5p2`.  But you have all sorts of functions, such as `Expand`, you can use to manipulate expressions into the forms you want.

Comment: Yes, but I disagree with Mathematica's thinking! Yes, `Expand` was part of solving this, too. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Both `Expand` and `N` appear to be necessary to coax Mathematica into a fully multiplied out version that distributes `Times` through `Rational` and across `Plus`.

Here's the longer answer …

`FullForm` was helpful in finding the solution.

```
In[170]:= br4QuadOne
FullForm[br4QuadOne]
Out[170]= {p4 -> 1/2 (mc4 + p3 + (-s3 + s4) \[Theta]max)}
Out[171]/FullForm= List[Rule[p4,Times[Rational[1,2],Plus[mc4,p3,Times[Plus[Times[-1, s3], s4],\[Theta]max]]]]]
```

It's the `Rational` inside the `Times` that appears to make Mathematica think it can't go further. When it's all just numbers, there's no problem.

```
In[191]:= Times[Rational[1, 2], 3.2]
Out[191]= 1.6
```

Once there's a variable in there, though, Mathematica is unwilling to distribute `Times` through `Rational` and across `Plus`.

```
In[209]:= Times[Rational[1, 2], Plus[t1, 5]]
Simplify[N[%]]
Out[209]= (5 + t1)/2
Out[210]= 0.5 (5. + t1)
```

`Expand` on its own isn't enough.

```
In[219]:= Expand[Times[Rational[1, 2], Plus[t1, 5]]]
Out[219]= 5/2 + t1/2
```

Finally, (and switching the order of `N` and `Expand` also works) …

```
In[212]:= N[Expand[Times[Rational[1, 2], Plus[t1, 5]]]]
Out[212]= 2.5 + 0.5 t1
```